# matplotlib animation looks different than sequenced imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two codes where I tried to turn it into an animation and the animation code and class shows an incomplete image (with missing colors) and the function at the bottom shows a full image and I can't see where the difference in the code is. I have a feeling it has something to do with the matplolib API but I am not sure...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from matplotlib import animation, image, pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis("off")


class SVDCompress():
    """compresses an image using singular value deocomposition"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.img = image.imread(
            urlopen('https://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/e/e1/Small_Mario_Cut-in_PD-SMBE.png/110px-Small_Mario_Cut-in_PD-SMBE.png')
        )
        #self.img = image.imread(filename)
        self.svd_image = np.zeros(self.img.shape)
        self.bytes = 0
        self.total_bytes = self.img.shape[0] * self.img.shape[1] * self.img.shape[2] / 1000
        self.layers = []

        # svd all the layers once so we don't have to do it again later
        for layer in range(self.img.shape[2]):
            self.layers.append(np.linalg.svd(self.img[:, :, layer]))

    def frames(self):
        """yield the frame number which gets passed to layers method"""
        for col in range(self.img.shape[1]):
            yield col

    def layer_no_animation(self, col: "animation index"):
        """layers calling plt.show() instead of figure"""
        for i in range(self.img.shape[2]):
            U, S, V = self.layers[i][0], self.layers[i][1], self.layers[i][2]
            self.bytes += (len(U[:, col]) + len(V[col, :])) / 1000
            self.svd_image[:, :, i] += np.outer(U[:, col] * S[col], V[col, :])

        if col % 30 == 0:
            plt.imshow(self.svd_image)
            plt.show()

    def layer(self, col: "animate index"):
        """add the new layers to the image"""
        for i in range(self.img.shape[2]):
            U, S, V = self.layers[i][0], self.layers[i][1], self.layers[i][2]
            self.bytes += (len(U[:, col]) + len(V[col, :])) / 1000
            self.svd_image[:, :, i] += np.outer(U[:, col] * S[col], V[col, :])

        if col % 30 == 0:
            ax.set_title(f"SVD column: {col} kbytes: {self.bytes}/{self.total_bytes}")
            ax.imshow(self.svd_image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #svd = SVDCompress()
    #anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, svd.layer, frames=svd.frames, interval=100)
    #anim.save('./mario-compression.gif', writer='imagemagick')

    svd = SVDCompress()
    for c in svd.frames():
        svd.layer_no_animation(c)
```

INSTRUCTIONS:

1. run once as is and as you close the plot windows, new ones will appear with a sharper image and correct colors.
2. comment out the part that runs in `__name__ == "__main"` and uncomment the code that I have commented out. This will save an animation and the colors will be messed up even though the code looks to do exactly the same thing.

I am thinking there is something different about the colors when calling `plt.imshow()` and `ax.imshow()` but I can't figure out what it is

...of course it could be something else that I missed

calling `plt.imshow()`...

[image]

calling `ax.imshow()`

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you turn this into a self-contained and runnable code, such that people have a chance to help.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: Imagemagick is installed. @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest ... It is self contained and runnable

Comment: It's not. Copy paste doesn't work. (To ping me use my name without the *a*)

Comment: you need to provide an image file of course, then copy paste should work

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I changed the code to be a little more compact and call an image from a url. It should work with copy and paste now but please read my instructions

Comment: Matplotlib can show images if they contain float values between 0.0 and 1.0; or integer values between 0 and 255. If they range from -0.05 to 4.7 or similar, almost anything can happen.

Comment: But then why does the plt.show() call work just fine and the other one doesn't. They use the same code and are given the same data but they display differently. How can I recreate the normalization that happens automatically with plt.show()? Ive tried everything I can think of and nothing comes out perfect

Comment: I mean, clearly we can investigate why the normalization and clipping is different in both cases, but at the end this is just an implementation detail and you wouldn't want to base your code on such unsupported feature. Instead make sure your data is sanitized before plotting it.